# Add Listview Item in a cell of Data Grid View

Tags: listview, datagridview, corresponding-records

I have `Listview` in `form1` having columns `AccountID, AccountName` and `AccountType` and `Form2` `Datagridview` unbound columns are `Date, DocNo AccountID, AccountName, Debit, Credit`.

i need two things:

1. when i select any row in `listview` and double click, only `AccountID` should be transferred in `AccountID` Cells of DatagridView and considering `AccountID` as Lookup value, Corresponding `AccountName` should also be displayed in `AccountName` Column of `Datgirdview`.
2. if i enter `AccountID` manually in the `AccountID` Cell of `DataGridView` Corresponding `AccountName` should  also be displayed in `AccountName` Column of `Datgirdview`

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you didn't tag your post with language and framework and didn't mentioned it either. I'm posting VB.NET winform solution.

1. `DoubleClick` on `ListView1`:

```
Private Sub ListView1_MouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ListView1.MouseDoubleClick
    ' provided the ValueMember of this ListView is set to AccountID
    If Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0 AndAlso Me.ListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells("AccountID").Value = CInt(Me.ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

2. Manual edit in `DataGridView`:

```
Private Sub dgRuns_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgRuns.CellEndEdit
    If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then   ' Only if AccountID column is edited
        Me.ListView1.SelectedItems.Clear()
        'Me.ListView1.Items().Selected = True
        For Each il In Me.ListView1.Items   ' look for selected value in column AccountID (of index 0)
            If il.subitem(0) = Me.dgRuns.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("AccountID").Value Then  ' when found particular AccountID
                il.focused = True    ' <<<<<<< focus on selected item
                il.selected = True   ' set it as selected 
                ListView1.Focus()    ' <<<<<<< focus on ListView1
                ListView1.Select()   ' <<<<<<< select ListView1
                Exit For             ' ...and exit the loopo
            End If
        Next il
    End If
End Sub
```

If you wanted a C# solution, you can use some [online converter](https://converter.telerik.com/).

Few comments, though:

1. I would suggest to use at least basic model-view approach, i.e. in form of `DataTables`.
2. You could avoid a lot of hassle by using `ComboBox` instead of `ListView` if possible, because it simplifies selection when `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` are set and used. Alternatively, if you need to use multi-column visual output, I'd choose another `DataGridView`. When properly set, looks as simple as `ListView`, without the odd data model behind.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your assumption is correct i need for vb.net. after checking the code will give you the feedback.

Comment: your first code is working fine but the second code is not working. no error is coming but corresponding Account is not displayed.

Comment: @TalatFarooq Technically, it is selecting the item (if you query selection of `ListView1`, you could check it). But indeed there's another oddity of `ListView`, when the focus is lost, it wouldn't show that an item is selected. If you click in, it would loose the selected item. I resolved it by selecting and focusing the `ListView1` itself. I'll modify my answer in a minute.

Comment: Brother, It is still not working. But somehow i find the solution by fetching data directly from database instead of listview. But it is made possible because of your help. thanks for your help.